# i want to design layout with card view stacked vertically with a 3dp margin between cards

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to design layout with card view stacked vertically with a 3dp margin between cards, but when I use the relative view as enclosing view of card views it does not give the results as expected, I am new at Android. this code snippet will help you to understand clearly:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dpl_it.m.hamzam.widgets.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/bluetooth_connect" />

        <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
            android:paddingTop="34dp"
            android:text="Bluetooth"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:textColor="#3F51B5" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card_view1"
                android:background="#FFFF"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_below` to set second `CardView` aligned below first `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Also set background color to `cardBackgroundColor` instead of `background`